# Trying to get duration of a audio but will return empty

Tags: javascript, audio, metadata

My code is to update the value of currentTime and FullTimeSong after loading from listening an event should update but each time I do it in my test only, it will give me an empty string because of the constructor (always the constructor value) even with loadedMetaData:

Here is how I done it in my component (some umiportant function are deleted)

```
export default class songPlayerTimeComponent {
  constructor () {
    this.songSelected = {};
    this.currentTime = " "
    this.timeSong = " "
    this.apiService = new SongService()
  }

  initialize (element) {
    element.innerHTML = `
    <span id="current_time_song"></span>
    <audio controls>
      <source type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    <span id="full_time_song"></span>`

    this.currentTimeEL = element.querySelector("#current_time_song")
    this.audioEl = element.querySelector('audio')
    this.timeSongEl = element.querySelector("#full_time_song")

    document.body.addEventListener('changeSongEvent', (event) => this.changeSongEvent(event.detail.songId))

    document.body.addEventListener('playSongEvent', () => this.playSongEvent())
    document.body.addEventListener('pauseSongEvent', () => this.pauseSongEvent())
    document.body.addEventListener('stopSongEvent', () => this.stopSongEvent())

    this.audioEl.addEventListener("play", () => this.songHasPlayed());
    this.audioEl.addEventListener("pause", () => this.songHasStopped())
    this.audioEl.addEventListener("ended", () => this.songHasEnded())

    this.audioEl.addEventListener("timeupdate", () => this.getCurrentTime())
    this.audioEl.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
        this.getSongTime() 
        this.renderComponent()
      }
    )
  }



  getCurrentTime(){
    let seconds = parseInt(this.audioEl.currentTime % 60);
    let minutes = parseInt((this.audioEl.currentTime / 60) % 60);
    if (seconds < 10) {
      seconds = '0' + seconds;
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
      minutes = '0' + minutes
    }

    this.currentTime = minutes + ':' + seconds;
  }

  async changeSongEvent (songId) {
    try{
      this.songSelected = await this.apiService.getSong(songId);
      this.audioEl.src = "./songs/" + this.songSelected.fileName;
      await this.audioEl.load()
    }
    catch (error) {
      this.displayErrorMessage (error)
    }
  }
  
  getSongTime() {
    const duration = parseInt(this.audioEl.duration)
    let seconds = duration % 60
    let minutes = Math.floor(duration / 60);
  
    seconds = ("0" + seconds).slice(-2);
    minutes = ("0" + minutes).slice(-2);
  
    this.timeSong = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    this.getCurrentTime();
  }
```

And here is my test to check if span has a innnerHTML:

```
            const songPlayerTimeComponent = new SongPlayerTimeComponent()
            const songSelected = songs[0]
            songPlayerTimeComponent.initialize(componentEl)

            document.body.dispatchEvent(
                new CustomEvent('changeSongEvent', {
                    detail: {
                    songId: songSelected.id
                    }
                })
            )
            await flushPromises()

            const currentTimeEL = document.querySelector('#current_time_song')
            expect(currentTimeEL.innerHTML).toEqual("9:00")
```

And finally the error:

```
AssertionError: expected '' to deeply equal '00:00'
 ❯ tests/songPlayerTimeComponent.test.js:61:42
     59|             const timeSongEL = document.querySelector('#full_time_song')
     60|             expect(timeSongEL.innerHTML).toBeDefined()
     61|             expect(timeSongEL.innerHTML).toEqual("00:00")
       |                                          ^
     62|         })
     63|

  - Expected   "00:00"
  + Received   ""

⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯[1/2]⎯

 FAIL  tests/songPlayerTimeComponent.test.js > songPlayerTimeComponent > success > Sur réception de l'événement global changeSongEvent, la durée totale de la chanson doit s'afficher.
AssertionError: expected '' to deeply equal '9:00'
 ❯ tests/songPlayerTimeComponent.test.js:79:45
     77|
     78|             const currentTimeEL = document.querySelector('#current_time_song')
     79|             expect(currentTimeEL.innerHTML).toEqual("9:00")
       |                                             ^
     80|         })
     81|

  - Expected   "9:00"
  + Received   ""
```

Answer (score 1):

For the Audio tag in HTML, you need to load the data. So you could either call the play function or the better way set the currentTime span after the canPlay event is lunch. [audio event in javaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement)

audio.addEventListener('canplay', e =>
"function to change the current time of the span"()
)

Comment: And for fulltimeSongBecause there is nothing inside it even when clling it from function to change the current time of the span

Comment: Even after the new version of change songEvent:
```async changeSongEvent (songId) {
    try{
      this.songSelected = await this.apiService.getSong(songId);
    }
    catch (error) {
      this.displayErrorMessage (error)
    }
    finally{
      this.audioEl.src = "./songs/" + this.songSelected.fileName;
      this.audioEl.load()
      this.getCurrentTime()
      this.getSongTime()
    }
  }```

It is giving me for fulltime aN;aN
Even with loading loadmetadata, or canplay